# Angular LazyLoad with callback Function fails to compile in AoT

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm try to compile a test SPA with ng build --prod --build-optimizer

I'm experiencing this error:

> expressions are not supported in decorators in 'ɵ0' angular loadchild

I found this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10789

where is suggested to change form this:

```
import {MainModule} from './../../main/main.module';

const sidenavRoutes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: SidenavComponent,
   canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', loadChildren: () =>MainModule}
    ]

  },

];
```

to

```
import {MainModule} from './../../main/main.module';

export function loadMainModule() {
  return require('es6-promise!./../../main/main.module')('MainModule');
}

const sidenavRoutes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: SidenavComponent,
   canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', loadChildren: loadMainModule}
    ]

  },

];
```

but I get this error:

> **MyPATH**\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:35
>                           throw new Error("Module '" + loader.path + "' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)");
>                           ^
>
> Error: Module
>   '**MyPATH**\node_modules\es6-promise\dist\es6-promise.js'
>   is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)

do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to have a look at: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: I know it, why? the function is used because I don't need to lazy load the module, but this way (with the () => Module) I can define the Routing module in a child module, otherwise the Routing doesn't work properly

Comment: I guess that I have to do somthing with the return require('es6-promise!./../../main/main.module')('MainModule');